# Detect if checkbox has been checked and contains a certain class?

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox that is within a loop, if the checkbox is the correct answer then it adds the class `correct-answer`:

```
<input class="correct <?php if($row['correct'] == "Yes") { ?>correct-answer<?php } ?>" data-progress="<?php echo $counter; ?>" type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="<?php echo $row['answer']; ?>" />
```

With Jquery, how can I detect if the checkbox has been checked AND if the checkbox includes the class `correct-answer`? I've got it working to detect if it's checked but I thought by adding `hasClass('.correct-answer')` it would detect both those things before running the if statement?

```
$('.correct-answer').change(function(){
    var item = $(this).data('progress');
if($(this).is(":checked").hasClass('.correct-answer')) {
        $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').removeClass("progress-incorrect");
        $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').addClass("progress-correct");
} else {
        $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').removeClass("progress-correct");
  $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').addClass("progress-incorrect");
}
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line below will not do what you want:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked").hasClass('.correct-answer')) {...}
```

The issue here is that `is(':checked')` returns a boolean, then you are trying to execute `hasClass('.correct-answer')` on it, which is obviously not working.

The right way is to have two different conditions in your `if` statement:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).hasClass('correct-answer')) {...}
```

Comment: Or simply using native DOM API `this.checked &&  this.classList.contains('correct-answer')`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dot from hasclass and add an "and":

```
if($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).hasClass('correct-answer')) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the alternative with the native DOM API:

```
if (this.checked && this.classList.contains('correct-answer'))
```

or even shorter

```
if (this.checked && this.matches('.correct-answer'))
```